# What is the solution in spark-scala to sort the data on non-key,non-integer column in a grouped data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### To sort the products data sorted by product price per category

I have an RDD of products - Columns : (product_id | product_category_id | product_name | product_description | product_price | product_image )

```scala
val prdMap = prd.map(r=> (r.split(",")(1).toInt,(r.split(",")(4),r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(2) )))
prdMap.take(5).foreach(println)

val groupByCategory = prdMap.groupByKey()
groupByCategory.take(2).foreach(println)
```

RDD elements are grouped as per Category_id correctly, after this i have to sort the data based on product_price in scala

It not sorting correctly if i keep product_price as string

```scala
groupByCategory.sortBy(_._2).take(2).foreach(println)
```

Actual Result

```
(36,CompactBuffer(
(12.99,789,TaylorMade Men's Burner LTD Golf Glove), 
(24.99,791,Hirzl Women's Trust Feel Golf Glove)
(13.99,790,FootJoy Men's StaCool Golf Glove) )
```

Expected Result

```
(36,CompactBuffer(
(12.99,789,TaylorMade Men's Burner LTD Golf Glove), 
(13.99,790,FootJoy Men's StaCool Golf Glove),
(24.99,791, Hirzl Women's Trust Feel Golf Glove) )
```

I have tried several methods - creating tuple by making product_price as key and sort based on that

1. Converting product_price to Float

```scala
val prdMap2 = prd.map(r=> (r.split(",")(1).toInt,(r.split(",")(4).toFloat,(r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(2) ))))
val groupByCategory2 = prdMap2.groupByKey()

prdMap2.groupByKey().sortBy(_._2).take(5).foreach(println)
prdMap2.groupByKey().keyBy(_._2).take(5).foreach(println)
```

both keyBy and sortBy are giving empty string error

```
19/08/11 19:51:29 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 300.0 (TID 553)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
```

2. converting into Data Frame and then groupBy product_category_id, but after groupBy, sortBy or orderBy are not working

```scala
val prdDF = prd.map(r=> (r.split(",")(1).toInt,r.split(",")(4).toFloat,r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(2) )).toDF("product_category_id","product_price","product_id","product_name")

scala> prdDF.groupBy("product_category_id")
res294: org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData = org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData@45172e99

scala> prdDF.groupBy("product_category_id").sort("product_price")
<console>:43: error: value sort is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData

scala> prdDF.groupBy("product_category_id").orderBy("product_price")
<console>:43: error: value orderBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
```

Questions

1. What is the solution in spark-scala to sort the data on non-key,non-integer column in a grouped data?
2. How to sort the data on 2 different non key, non int columns one in ascending another in descending order in scala? (This is related to another problem i'm facing)

I'm a beginner in spark-scala, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the `RDD[String]` input into a `RDD[(K,V)]` with the `value` part consisting of the target numeric element for sorting, as shown below:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("36,12.99,789,TaylorMade Men's Burner LTD Golf Glove"),
  ("36,24.99,791,Hirzl Women's Trust Feel Golf Glove"),
  ("36,13.99,790,FootJoy Men's StaCool Golf Glove")
))

import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val rdd2 = rdd.map{ line =>
  val arr = line.split(",")
  val a0 = Try(arr(0).toInt) match { case Success(i) => i; case Failure(_) => 0 }
  val a1 = Try(arr(1).toDouble) match { case Success(d) => d; case Failure(_) => 0.0 }

  (a0, (a1, arr.tail))
}

rdd2.groupByKey.mapValues( _.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2) ).collect
// res1: Array[(Int, List[Array[String]])] = Array((36, List(
//   Array(12.99, 789, TaylorMade Men's Burner LTD Golf Glove),
//   Array(13.99, 790, FootJoy Men's StaCool Golf Glove),
//   Array(24.99, 791, Hirzl Women's Trust Feel Golf Glove)
// )))
```

If you're on `Spark 2.4+`, consider transforming the `RDD[(K,V)]` into a `DataFrame` and apply [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array_sort(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to the grouped array in a `groupBy/collect_list` aggregation:

```
val df = rdd2.toDF("c1", "c2")

df.groupBy("c1").agg(array_sort(collect_list($"c2")).as("c2_sorted_list"))
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the response Leo, i have tried using the first method on sample data and on source file .....on sample data its working correctly , however when it comes to source file its throwing error val prdMap2 = prd.map { r=> 
val arr = r.split(",")
     | (arr(1).toInt, (arr(4).toDouble,arr.tail ))
     | }
prdMap2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Double, Array[String]))] = 

scala> prdMap2.groupByKey.mapValues( _.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2) ).collect
19/08/15 01:49:00 ERROR 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: Source file format ...scala> prd.take(5).foreach(println)
1,2,Quest Q64 10 FT. x 10 FT. Slant Leg Instant U,,59.98,http://images.acmesports.sports/Quest+Q64+10+FT.+x+10+FT.+Slant+Leg+Instant+Up+Canopy
2,2,Under Armour Men's Highlight MC Football Clea,,129.99,http://images.acmesports.sports/Under+Armour+Men%27s+Highlight+MC+Football+Cleat
3,2,Under Armour Men's Renegade D Mid Football Cl,,89.99,http://images.acmesports.sports/Under+Armour+Men%27s+Renegade+D+Mid+Football+Cleat

Comment: @Twinkle047, it looks like some of your numeric fields consist of invalid or empty values.  I've revised my answer to cover those cases (default to 0's, which you might want to reset accordingly).

Comment: There is 1 error record in source that's why it was throwing error. After removing error record, its giving wierd results.  Input- prdMap2.take(5).foreach(println)
(2,(59.98,1,Quest Q64 10 FT. x 10 FT. Slant Leg Instant U))
(2,(129.99,2,Under Armour Men's Highlight MC Football Clea))
(2,(89.99,3,Under Armour Men's Re
Output-prdMap2.groupByKey.mapValues( _.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2) ).collect
res338: Array[(Int, List[String])] = Array((52,List(1155, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166, 1167, 1168, 1169, 1170, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1176, 1177, 1159, 1160, 1154, 1156, 1157, 1158)),

Comment: i have used this function val prdMap2 = prd.
filter(product => product.split(",")(4) != "").
map { r=> 
  val arr = r.split(",")
(arr(1).toInt, (arr(4).toDouble,arr(0),arr(2) ))
} when i use val prdMap3 = prd.
filter(product => product.split(",")(4) != "").
map { r=> 
  val arr = r.split(",")
(arr(1).toInt, (arr(4).toDouble,arr.tail ))
} ....its not sorting based on product_price

Comment: Sorting isn't performed in the transformations described in your comment, but is done via `sortBy` in `groupByKey/mapValues`.  Anyway, it's hard to troubleshoot programming problem from comments.  I would suggest that you narrow down the exact problem you're now experiencing, and create a separate question with a minuscule dataset of simplified data structure that can replicate the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Window function to sort your data because your data is distributed and the column on which you are sorting might not be in same partition which can give wrong result if you use orderBy.
Try something like this:

```
val df = Seq((1,101,"xyz","ejflwkef",12.27,"image1"),(2,101,"xyz","ejflwkef",14.27,"image2"),(3,102,"xyz","ejflwkef",12.27,"image3")).toDF("product_id","product_category_id","product_name","product_description","product_price","product_image")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val byCategoryId = Window.partitionBy("product_category_id").orderBy(desc("product_price"))

df.withColumn("rnk",row_number over byCategoryId).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

> **step1 For RDD**

```
val prdMap = prd.map(r=> (r.split(",")(1).toInt,(r.split(",")(4),r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(2) )))
prdMap.take(5).foreach(println)
val groupByCategory = prdMap.groupByKey()
groupByCategory.take(2).foreach(println)
```

groupByCategory is returning RDD[(Int, Iterable[(String, String, String)])].

1. firstly you will need to use the map for iterable then you will be able to sort the data.
2. Use map to get data as the element and after getting an element(value) from map, sort the data whatever order you want  [iterable with sort by](http://discuss.itversity.com/t/sort-by-iterable-value-in-a-tuple-using-scala/9095)

> **Step 2 For dataFrame**

for sorting data with column and without using aggregation is achieved by using window function in spark and spark-sql.
[for window function prefer this](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

Comment: Thanks for response Mahesh, link you have provided working perfectly fine for 2 fields, one key and another Iterable field. But i have 4 fields, one key and (float,string,string). I want to group by key column and sort by float column within 2nd part of tuple. Will try 2nd method DF and let you know if i found result.